# Azure API Management Restrict multiple caller IP Address

Tags: policy, azure-api-management

If I look at the below URl for restricting IP Address in API Management with its policy "IP-Filter", we can either limit single IP Address or a range. Is there a way I can filter different IP Address like 172.2.2.2, 122.2.2.4,
134.2.2.3?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs

Thanks and Regards,
Manu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Graphical interface allows you to add many IP addresses in "Filter IP addresses" policy.

[image]

It's changed to the following xml expression

```
    <ip-filter action="allow">
        <address>10.10.1.1</address>
        <address>10.10.1.200</address>
    </ip-filter>
```

Comment: If I want implement for certain scope (e.g. API endpoint level which is operations) where should we place the values?