# Azure API Management Restrict multiple caller IP Address API in API endpoint level

Tags: azure-api-management

I wanted to restrict some IP's in Azure APIM policy level.

I went thro below links;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs

[Azure API Management Restrict multiple caller IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480617/azure-api-management-restrict-multiple-caller-ip-address)

But not sure how can I do this to API end-point level using `policy scope`

I have below code in the policy.xml:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- statements to be applied to the request go here -->
        <authentication-certificate thumbprint="@((string)context.Variables[&quot;ClientCertificateThumbprint&quot;])" />
        <rate-limit-by-key calls="100" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault(&quot;Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key&quot;))" />        
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="600">
                <method>*</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
            <expose-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </expose-headers>
        </cors>
        <ip-filter action="allow">
          <address>55.11.187.20</address>
          <address-range from="186.168.95.0" to="186.168.95.20" />
        </ip-filter>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />

        <!-- statements to be applied before the request is forwarded to 
         the backend service go here -->
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />

        <!-- statements to be applied to the response go here -->
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
        <!-- statements to be applied if there is an error condition go here -->
    </on-error>
</policies
```

>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using control flow in Advanced policies you can change the scope to API endpoint level (operation) to restrict IP addresses as below

```
<choose>
      <when condition="@(context.Operation.Id.Equals(&quot;StatusGet&quot;))">
        <ip-filter action="allow">
          <address>55.11.187.20</address>
           <address-range from="186.168.95.0" to="186.168.95.20" />
        </ip-filter>
      </when>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies

Comment: Ah. So you wanted to apply IP filter to a single operation while using non operation scope. This is correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to Azure portal, your APIM service, APIs.
2. Click API you want to apply IP filter to
3. In the "Inbound processing" section click "Add policy" and select IP filter.

Comment: In my case we can't directly edit `APIM policy` So it has to be done through deployment via `VSTS`. Within the code we have `policy.xml`  where we can edit and deploy. But through current policy file it update `Inbound processing` in API level not the end-point level. But I can see `Inbound processing` in end-point level as well. Is there a way of doing this at end point level?

Comment: Sure. This policy can be applied at any scope, but it will also be enforced only at that scope. If you place it at global scope - every call - no matter to what API - will be in restricted. If you add it to API scope - only calls to that API will be e.t.c.

Comment: I get that, but the question is how to code the `policy.xml` file to retrict ONLY API end-point level. I have updated the complete `policy.xml` file in the question which update the global level currently.